# How to add animation effects to fade in/out text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this working well.

Would anyone know how to add an animate up effect as it each one fades in?

So the next text would fade in and up from 0 opacity at the same time.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var quotes = $(".rotate-text li");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(4000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();
});
```

```css
.rotate-text li {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rotate-text">
  <li>Some intro text</li>
  <li>Oh look at me</li>
  <li>Here I am again</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how I would do it:
https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/QzKKEG

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var quotes = $(".rotate-text li");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
      ++quoteIndex;
      var quote = quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length);

      quote.addClass('active')
      setTimeout(function() {
        quote.removeClass('active');
        showNextQuote();
      }, 4000);
  }

  showNextQuote();
});
```

CSS

```
.rotate-text {
    position: relative;
}
.rotate-text li {
    position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-1.5em);
}
.rotate-text li.active {
    opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0em);
}
```

**I believe it is a better idea to let CSS do the styles. Only trigger classes with jQuery.**

Comment: Cheers for that, css works for me.

Little tweeting and got it working pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var quotes = $(".rotate-text li");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .delay(4000)
      .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();
});
```

```css
.rotate-text li {
  display: none;
}


/* Animation */

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
  opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rotate-text">
  <li class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp">Some intro text</li>
  <li class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp">Oh look at me</li>
  <li class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp">Here I am again</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Be sure to add `-moz-animation-fill-mode` and `-moz-animation-duration` for browser compatibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.rotate-text {
    position: relative;
}

.rotate-text li {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
            transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility .4s, -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility .4s, -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility .4s, transform .4s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility .4s, transform .4s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility .4s, transform .4s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;
}

.rotate-text li.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);

}
```